# Can clone but not pull from git repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have cloned and been doing (push/pull) from my private repo on bitbucket. Suddenly, I can't pull anymore. When I run git pull in my work directory, it says:

```
$ git pull
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '2406:da00:ff00::34cc:ea4a' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

However, I can clone the same repo to a different place on the same host. It has always been working. Only thing I recently did was, I was trying to get git pull work through an Asnsible script (which didn't work).

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Do you have different `fetch` and `push` entries in your `.git/config` file for that remote repo?

Comment: Getting at the same info @match is asking a different way, does `git remote -v` give you different answer on the fresh close than in your sandbox with a problem?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. `git remote -v` in previously created repo shows identical lines for both fetch and push, BUT they are different from what I get in the freshly cloned repo. The difference being, the former using '/' in the repo URL while the latter using ':'. 

origin git@bitbucket.org/username/repo.git
versus
origin git@bitbucket.org:username/repo.git

Comment: And does `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org` show the appropriate username or access key?

Comment: Please elaborate about '/' vs ':' - where do you see one versus the other?

Comment: I see the difference when running `git remote -v` in the two directories, one where I had already cloned the repo and been working (which doesn't allow pull anymore) and the other,  in the freshly cloned repo. I also see the same difference in the respective .git/config files.

Comment: A correction: Actually, I have missed one important detail. The url in the two cases are as follows:

url = git@bitbucket.org:sakzje/sb.git (not working)

versus

url = ssh://git@@bitbucket.org:sakzje/sb.git (working)

Comment: I edited `.git/config` and changed the url. Now it works! Really have no idea how this got changed. Is it possible that Ansible (with possibly wrong parameters) did this?

Thank you all for helping with this!